# How to get the HTML line that's created by onclick event

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests

While I was trying to write a python script that scrapes the HTML of a website, I ran into a problem that I can't seem to find a way to scrape a part of the website caused by the onclick event.

[screenshot before onclick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iP2z1.png)
[screenshot after onclick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4Jlo.png)

(I tried posting the screenshots of the HTML to show you the difference, but stackoverflow won't let me for some reason)

After clicking on the onclick, it creates a new class called bet_all, which couldn't have been seen previously. How can I get that HTML for bet_all class from my python?

I'm currently using the requests.get function to scrape the data.

Comment: Use Playwright, or the older Selenium. Don't roll your own.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm trying to run this on multiple pages, so it'd be much more convenient if I could go to different pages and scrape them instead of having selenium physically go to each page, clicking on the buttons, then scraping.

Is there no way to do it within the script?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @flying_penguin... what? whether you or selenium visit a page makes zero difference? You just script selenium to go to every page you need, it doesn't magically stop working after loading a single page, you just load _another page_ after scraping the first one =)